# Table Compilation Error

Tags: tables

I wish to produce a table in LaTeX, and I have the following code:

```
\begin{document}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

    \begin{table}[htbp]\centering
    \caption{\label{} 
    \textbf{} }\begin{tabular} {@{} l r r r r @{}} \\ \hline
    \textbf{decade   variable } & \textbf{      mean} & \textbf{        sd} & \textbf{       min} & \textbf{       max} \\
    \hline
    1870             FX  &   .0067936 &   .0213805 &          0 &   .2598524 \\
    1880             FX  &    .007234 &   .0247923 &          0 &   .4339035 \\
    1890             FX  &    .006457 &   .0262819 &          0 &   .5958799 \\
    1900             FX  &   .0053169 &   .0250915 &          0 &   .6504794 \\
    1910             FX  &   .0040217 &   .0212009 &          0 &   .6297928 \\
    1920             FX  &   .0037496 &   .0183218 &          0 &   .6062132 \\
    1930             FX  &   .0032832 &   .0180154 &          0 &   .6439216 \\
    1940             FX  &   .0017647 &   .0124483 &          0 &   .5444609 \\
    1950             FX  &   .0013486 &   .0098272 &          0 &   .5584736 \\
    1960             FX  &   .0013742 &   .0109455 &          0 &   .9799178 \\
    1970             FX  &   .0018738 &   .0152187 &          0 &    1.62081 \\
    1980             FX  &   .0018762 &   .0126865 &          0 &   1.141317 \\
    1990             FX  &   .0016994 &   .0114209 &          0 &   .7125121 \\
    2000             FX  &   .0018457 &   .0132574 &          0 &   1.298152 \\
    2010             FX  &   .0018348 &   .0117263 &          0 &   1.262003 \\
    \hline
    \multicolumn{5}{@{}l}
    \end{tabular}
    \end{table}

`\end{document}
```

I receive an error that a missing `\endcsname` is inserted on the `\end{table}` line. Any help on this is much appreciated!

Comment: `\multicolumn` takes three arguments: the number of columns, column specification, and what you want to go in that space.  What are you trying to do with your multicolumn?

Comment: You are missing an argument in the last `\multicolumn` command... With `\multicolumn{5}{@{}l}{test}` it compiles without errors